# Bcc Email Order Notification in Woocommerce with ACF

Tags: php, woocommerce, notifications, advanced-custom-fields

my client wants to separate his clients by Agency according to their location, each agency has an administration account. He would like the order email to go to the selected customer's agency. I created a radio button for customer accounts with ACF and I want to CC the order email to the agency email in question and that's where I'm blocking. I can't add the right condition to send the email.

Code ACF :

```
    if( function_exists('acf_add_local_field_group') ):

acf_add_local_field_group(array(
    'key' => 'group_62b97460daadb',
    'title' => 'Agence Barrault / AutoFit',
    'fields' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'field_62b9746e368c2',
            'label' => 'Sélectionner une Agence',
            'name' => 'agence',
            'type' => 'radio',
            'instructions' => '',
            'required' => 1,
            'conditional_logic' => 0,
            'wrapper' => array(
                'width' => '',
                'class' => '',
                'id' => '',
            ),
            'choices' => array(
                1 => 'Test',
                2 => 'La Rochelle',
                3 => 'Saintes',
                4 => 'Rochefort',
            ),
            'allow_null' => 0,
            'other_choice' => 0,
            'default_value' => 1,
            'layout' => 'vertical',
            'return_format' => 'value',
            'save_other_choice' => 0,
        ),
    ),
    'location' => array(
        array(
            array(
                'param' => 'user_form',
                'operator' => '==',
                'value' => 'all',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'menu_order' => 0,
    'position' => 'normal',
    'style' => 'default',
    'label_placement' => 'top',
    'instruction_placement' => 'label',
    'hide_on_screen' => '',
    'active' => true,
    'description' => '',
    'show_in_rest' => 0,
));

endif;
```

My code :

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'bcc_to_email_headers', 10, 3 );
function bcc_to_email_headers( $headers, $email_id, $order ) {

    if ( $email_id === 'new_order' ) {
        $value = get_field( 'field_62b9746e368c2', 'agence' );

        if ( $value == [1] ) {
            $headers .= "Bcc: Name <exemple@email.com> \r\n";
        }
    }
    return $headers;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this line

```
if ( $value == [1] ) {
```

to

```
if ( $value === 1 ) {
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works, but halfway, if I add new email addresses to segment (example: value === 2), assigned to another recipient, it sends a copy to the first email regardless of the value of $value

Comment: what's the output of `$value = get_field( 'field_62b9746e368c2', 'agence' );`?